# start repl debugging session on exception in clojure

Tags: debugging, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

How to automatically start a REPL debugging session on exception? I'm running my app via lein via ring-jetty-adapter. Stackoverflow wants me to expand my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete guess, but I would start looking at creating a middleware function to catch the exception, then possibly use nrepl to communicate it back to your client... Just a vague idea though.